# Ubuntu 18.04 NFS Share - No Files Visible

Tags: 18.04, nfs

I have 2 Ubuntu 18.04 servers running.  media-01 has an NFS mount from storage-01, and it has worked without issue for a couple of months now.  2 days ago, media-01 stopped being able to see the files on the NFS share, and the permissions are correct.

The mount occurs without issue, and I can create a directory on media-01's mountpoint, but that directory is not visible on storage-01.    No log entries are occuring for errors, just normal mount successful messages.

storage-01 has /etc/exports configured as

```
/Storage    10.0.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

media-01 has /etc/fstab configured as

```
10.0.1.72:/Storage /Storage nfs defaults,user,exec
```

I did have the /etc/fstab as

```
10.0.1.72:/Storage /Storage nfs defaults,nfsvers=3 0 0
```

but as I have been troubleshooting, I removed nfsvers

I am at a loss, rebooting has had no effect, changing the mountpoint has changed nothing.

I created a secondary export and that does reflect changes, and it is configured the same way.

Permissions are nobody:users owns the directories with 777 permissions across the board.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So I had 2 separate NFS disks present within /Storage, by creating separate export and mount points for each disk, I resolved this issue.

I noticed that when I did an ls -la on /Storage it showed the free space for sda2 on storage-01, rather than sdb1 and sdb2.